# Sizing a spring

Tags: springs, 3d-printing, coil-spring

I am attempting to 3D print my own Quad lock mount and require a spring. I've taken some measurements but don't know how to search for where I can buy more springs. Dimensions:
12mm height, 20mm OD. Thanks

Comment: We don’t do “buy” questions.

Comment: Century Springs is a wonderful resource. www.centuryspring.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dimensions: 12mm height, 20mm OD.

You need more information than that to select or design a spring. Typically you need to specify several of the following:

- The free length.
- The force required at L<sub>1</sub>. (Remember the spring exerts zero force when in its uncompressed state.)
- The force required at L<sub>2</sub>, typically the maximum load and not quite fully compressed.
- The *rate* expressed in N/mm or colonial measurement units.

I only had to work through this once and realised that to get a reasonably consistent force over a range of positions that quite a long spring was required.

Search for online compression spring calculator should get you something to work with and once you have a specification you can look at standard catalog parts.

Answer (score 0):

I use the search string "spring fasteners" in the images mode. You will see pictures with spring on it. Clicking on the image you will find the hardware store.

An alternative is to use an internet calculator and follow the links provided there. As an example see: [www.tribology-abc.com](http://www.tribology-abc.com)